# How to cast an Object from Javascript to a class?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I have the following ActionScript code :

```
import flash.external.*
public function req(temp:Object):void{
    var request:URLRequest=temp as URLRequest; // request is then null
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback('call',req);
```

and the follwing JavaScript code

```
document.getElementById('flash').call(({url:"http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/flashredirect/?https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/accounts/self/profile",digest:null,method:"DELETE",requestHeaders:null,data:null,contentType:null}));
```

Or is it possible to cast the Javascript object to Urlrequest from JavaScript ? If not, how to do it from ActionScript ?
Please note I’m not interested in keeping the Original JavaScript Object…

Comment: The point is`URLRequest.method`is only checked from the playerglobal.

Comment: I think you can pass only basic data this way, i.e. **Boolean**s, **Number**s, **String**s, **Array**s and generic **Object**s. Simply, anything you can losslessly convert to **JSON** and back.

Comment: @Organis though from what I tried, there’s no problem at performing the reverse : I mean converting a Urlrequest to a Javascript Object. Indeed this is how I got the example (where I just replaced post).

Comment: @Organis [do you think it’s possible](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()) using [the right format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) ? I mean it wouldn’t be a problem to serialize into ᴀᴍꜰ from JavaScript.

Comment: Why not JSON? AMF is a bother.

Comment: @Organis because [this is the only function I found for deserializing back to Actionscipt classes so far](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()).

Comment: Yes, these are used to serialize objects other than plain data. Still, even if it is possible to serialize/deserialize objects between AS3 and JS correctly, the deserialized objects will not contain direct links to JS originals, they will be just copies inside AS3 sandbox.

Comment: @Organis question edited… I don’t care about the JavaScript original Objects… I just want to perfom PUT requests…